# Saving the data

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, hardware-failure

If this is not the correct forum for this hardware question, and I suspect it's not, I would appreciate a pointer to the proper forum.

My laptop computer has convincingly died. "Dead and rotted!," as my housmate puts it. I Can no longer get it even to power up. It contains a 3 TB hard drive and a 200 GB SSD. Jointly, these drives contain about 15 years of my own work and a number of huge data sets I have been at some trouble to gather, including Census and climate data. A lot of this is no longer central to my interests. The problem is that there is no way anyone but me could possibly distinguish the trash from the treasures. I would like to spend a week or so sorting these out this out and tossing the obsolete. The only way I have thought of to do this is to buy a cheap backup computer and transfer the drives to it. 8ve swapped disk drives before, but what I know about hardware could be written on the head of a very small pin.

I hope someone can tell me if there are any compatibility issues I need to check for when purchasing an interim machine, besides the availability of two empty bays, and if so, what should I look at to inform myself about them? This whole process has been somewhat traumatic.  I am living in a city which is new to me, and my my little red Prius has a serious electrical system problem I have been unable to precisely identify, and these problems interact to make everything more complicated than it should be.If I were still in Oakland I could carry the computer to people I would trust with any technical problem. I do not yet have that kind of local knowledge here in Findlay, OH. Two weeks unable to work is making me crazy.

Comment: I guess you can open up the bottom panel of your laptop and take out the SSD and HDD. Buy a compatible casing, for example: https://www.amazon.in/COOLCOLD-2-5-Sata-Casing-Transparent/dp/B09QS4JBP1/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?keywords=HDD+Casing&qid=1673494988&sr=8-1-spons&sp_csd=d2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9hdGY&psc=1, and access the data from any computer. This solution obviously takes into consideration that the drives are not encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few easy ways to access the data, **if it is not locked by Bitlocker or otherwise encrypted**. If encrypted, [you might not be able to access data easily... or at all](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dc4b0c7d-bb1b-4a74-bc06-7d084fb38926/moving-bitlocker-encrypted-drive-to-new-computer?forum=win10itprogeneral).

1. Easiest, **if the PC can boot to BIOS** (see the manual for your PC to get to BIOS): use disk imaging tools such as [Macrium Reflect Free](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) to make a rescue USB. Then create an image of the two drives to an external HDD with sufficient room. A 4 TB drive lists for [~US$80 at NewEgg](https://www.newegg.com/p/pl?d=4%20tb%20external%20hdd), for example. This will save *all* data, programs and even the operating system files so that you can salvage data at your leisure. Use the external drive with your new PC to make images on a regular basis to reduce risk of losing data!
2. Again, **if the PC can boot to BIOS,** make a bootable USB drive, such as [a Ubuntu Live USB](https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/), [Hiren’s BootCD PE](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/), [Ultimate Boot CD](https://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) or one of [the alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/hiren39s-bootcd/). Plug in an external HDD with sufficient room and copy over *everything* from both SSD and old HDD, or just desired files.
3. Buy an external case for the HDD and SSD (you might different cases for each depending on connection types). Remove the drives from the old machine, plug them into the case, and connect to another PC. **N.B.** At first, **mount them read-only** to prevent data loss or damage; after data is recovered, they can be mounted normally (red/write) and used for additional data storage. An external SSD or HDD case might cost US$10 to $30, as in [these examples](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=external+USB+case+for+hdd&sprefix=external+usb+case+for+hdd%2Caps%2C107&ref=nb_sb_noss_2). **Be sure to get one compatible with the drives.**
4. It is not as good an idea to mount them directly inside a new PC because there may be conflicts in boot order. If the first three suggestions are unfeasible, you *can* do that, though. Again, **mount read-only**.